# Will Samsung Galaxy S2 cases fit a Focus S?

Tags: accessories, samsung-focus

The selection of good Samsung Focus S cases is rather limited. I've noticed, however, the striking similarity in the hardware and shape of my friend's Android Galaxy S2. They appear to be almost the same phone.

Would a Galaxy S2 case fit well on a Focus S?

Answer (score 4):

The Focus S corners are rounder, the camera cut is different, the front sensors and back speakers are on different sides and the Focus S has a physical camera. So a tight fitting case will not work.

However, since the dimensions are similar (67x126x8 mm [Focus S] vs. 66x125x8 mm [Galaxy S II]) a flip style case that clips in on the sides *may* work.